# Select where multiple fields are not in subquery (excluding join)

Tags: subquery, abap, exists, opensql

I have a requirement to pull records, that do not have history in an archive table. 2 Fields of 1 record need to be checked for in the archive.

In technical sense my requirement is a left join where right side is 'null' (a.k.a. an excluding join), which in abap openSQL is commonly implemented like this (for my scenario anyways):

```
Select * from xxxx            //xxxx is a result for a multiple table join
where xxxx~key not in         (select key from archive_table where [conditions] ) 
  and xxxx~foreign_key not in (select key from archive_table where [conditions] )
```

Those 2 fields are also checked against 2 more tables, so that would mean a total of 6 subqueries.

Database engines that I have worked with previously usually had some methods to deal with such problems (such as excluding join or outer apply).

For this particular case I will be trying to use ABAP logic with 'for all entries', but **I would still like to know if it is possible to use results of a sub-query to check more than than 1 field or use another form of excluding join logic on multiple fields** using SQL (without involving application server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested quite a few variations of sub-queries in the life-cycle of the program I was making. `NOT EXISTS` with multiple field check (shortened example below) to exclude based on 2 keys works in certain cases. 
Performance acceptable (processing time is about 5 seconds), although, it's noticeably slower than the same query when excluding based on 1 field.

```
Select * from xxxx            //xxxx is a result for a multiple table inner joins and 1 left join ( 1-* relation )
where NOT EXISTS  (
   select key from archive_table 
   where key = xxxx~key OR key = XXXX-foreign_key 
)
```

---

**EDIT:** 
With changing requirements (for more filtering) a lot has changed, so I figured I would update this. The construct I marked as `XXXX` in my example contained a single left join ( where main to secondary table relation is `1-*` ) and it appeared relatively fast.

This is where context becomes helpful for understanding the problem:

- Initial requirement: pull all `vendors`, without financial records in 3
  tables.
- Additional requirements: also exclude based on alternative
  `payers` (`1-*` relationship). This is what example above is based on.
- More requirements: also exclude based on alternative `payee` (`*-*` relationship between `payer` and `payee`).

Many-to-many join exponentially increased the record count within the   construct I labeled `XXXX`, which in turn produces a lot of unnecessary work. For instance: a single customer with 3 `payers`, and 3 `payees` produced 9 rows, with a total of 27 fields to check (3 per row), when in reality there are only 7 unique values.

At this point, moving left-joined tables from main query into sub-queries **and splitting them** gave significantly better performance.
than any smarter looking alternatives.

```
select * from lfa1 inner join lfb1 
       where 
          ( lfa1~lifnr not in ( select lifnr from bsik where bsik~lifnr = lfa1~lifnr )
       and lfa1~lifnr not in ( select wyt3~lifnr from wyt3 inner join t024e on wyt3~ekorg = t024e~ekorg and wyt3~lifnr <> wyt3~lifn2
                                                        inner join bsik  on bsik~lifnr = wyt3~lifn2 where wyt3~lifnr = lfa1~lifnr and t024e~bukrs = lfb1~bukrs  )
       and lfa1~lifnr not in ( select lfza~lifnr from lfza inner join bsik  on bsik~lifnr = lfza~empfk where lfza~lifnr = lfa1~lifnr )
          )
           and [3 more sets of sub queries like the 3 above, just checking different tables].
```

---

**My Conclusion**:

- When exclusion is based on a single field, both `not in`/`not exits` work. One might be better than the other, depending on filters you use.
- When exclusion is based on 2 or more fields and you don't have many-to-many join in main query, `not exists ( select .. from table where id = a.id or id = b.id or... )` appears to be the best.
- The moment your exclusion criteria implements a many-to-many relationship within your main query, I would recommend looking for an optimal way to implement multiple sub-queries instead (even having a sub-query for each key-table combination will perform better than a many-to-many join with 1 good sub-query, that looks good).

Anyways, any additional insight into this is welcome.

**EDIT2**: Although it's slightly off topic, given how my question was about sub-queries, I figured I would post an update. After over a year I had to revisit the solution I worked on to expand it. I learned that **proper excluding join works**. I just failed horribly at implementing it the first time.

```
select header~key 
from headers left join items on headers~key = items~key
where items~key is null
```

Answer (score 0):

> if it is possible to use results of a sub-query to check more than
>   than 1 field or use another form of excluding join logic on multiple
>   fields

No, it is not possible to check two columns in subquery, as [SAP Help](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenwhere_logexp_in_subquery.htm) clearly says:

> The clauses in the subquery *subquery_clauses* must constitute a **scalar**
>   subquery.

*Scalar* is keyword here, i.e. it should return exactly one column.

Your subquery can have multi-column key, and such syntax is completely legit:

```
SELECT  planetype, seatsmax
  FROM  saplane AS plane
 WHERE seatsmax < @wa-seatsmax AND
       seatsmax >= ALL ( SELECT  seatsocc
                           FROM  sflight
                           WHERE carrid = @wa-carrid AND
                                 connid = @wa-connid     )
```

however you say that these two fields should be checked against different tables

> Those 2 fields are also checked against **two** more tables

so it's not the case for you. Your only choice seems to be multi-join.

**P.S.** `FOR ALL ENTRIES` does not support negation logic, you cannot just use some sort of `NOT IN FOR ALL ENTRIES`, it won't be that easy.

Comment: Your answer pointed me towards a possible solution. I am currently testing a variant that uses a `NOT EXISTS` addition in `WHERE` clause. For some reason it didn't immediately occur to me I can compare as many fields as I want there. I am not sure about performance yet, however, so I will try to update the question when I have some results.

Comment: @Zero, agreed. I think NOT EXISTS is the right answer. You may compare several fields between the main query and the subquery. Please consider adding an answer so that we can vote for it.